# Renumbering rows after ordering in R programme

Tags: r

I have ordered a set of rows to get this:

```
2   1983  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1495 0.1395     NA      452 0.0764      4      0  06/02/83
4   1983  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1193 0.1113     NA       32 0.0764      4      2  07/20/83
14  1983  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1064 0.1064     NA       26 0.0763      6      2  08/03/83
17  1983  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1110 0.1010 0.1010      176 0.0763      7      4  08/08/83
24  1983  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1293 0.1215     NA      452 0.0763      4      0  09/12/83
41  1984  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1325 0.1225     NA      452 0.0740      4      0  06/20/84
45  1984  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1425 0.1325     NA       32 0.0741      4      2  07/17/84
47  1984  TRI-COUNTY  TRAUTH         0.1395 0.1395 0.1250       91 0.0741     14     11  07/16/84
```

But I want to renumber these such that its 1,2,3,4,etc...

Can someone please help?

Comment: Not without [considerably more information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364), no.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you just looking for something like this?:

```
row.names(datasetname) <- 1:nrow(datasetname)
```

Alternatively, if the first column in your example data is a variable (say `V1`) in a dataframe and not the `row.names`, this will work:

```
datasetname$V1 <- 1:nrow(datasetname)
```

Comment: `rownames(dataset) <- NULL` is another approach

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way to do it:

```
rownames(dataset) = NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, normally used when binding rows:

```
dataset <- rbind( dataset , make.rows.names=FALSE )
```